# How to force FastCGI to encode form data as UTF-8 as CGI.pm has option?

Tags: perl, utf-8, cgi, fastcgi

Trying to run old CGI-scripts under FastCGI. Printing without extra parameters gives proper output: `print $q->div( $q->param("text") )`

But when printing out with extra parameters hash for CGI-methods `print $q->div( {-id=>"id"}, $q->param("text") )`, it ruins UTF-8 formed data ('õäöüžš' -> 'ÃµÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼Å¾Å¡')

It happens only with CGI parameters, in script defined variables work fine (examples 3 and 4).  Everything works perfecty under ordinary CGI  (with "-utf8"-flag ).

FastCGI-turned example script, called as `test.fcgi?text=õäöüžš` should give four equal blocks:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w --

use strict;
use CGI::Fast qw(:all);
use locale;
use utf8;

BEGIN {
        binmode(STDIN);                       # Form data
        binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');  # HTML
        binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)');  # Error messages
}

my ($q) = ();
my $test = "õäöüžš";

while ($q = new CGI::Fast) {

        print $q->header(-type=>"text/html", -charset=>"utf-8"), 
                $q->start_html(-encoding=>"utf-8");

        print "1: ",
                $q->div(  $q->param('text') ),
                "<br />",
                "2: ",
                $q->div( {-id=>"id"},  $q->param('text') ),
                "<br />",
                "3: ",
                $q->div(  $test ),
                "<br />",
                "4: ",
                $q->div( {-id=>"id"},  $test ),
        $q->end_html();

}
```

First block is fine, second broken, 3rd and 4th also fine:

Ordinary CGI-example as that gives all 4 right way:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w --

use strict;
use CGI qw(:all -utf8);
use locale;
use utf8;

BEGIN {
        binmode(STDIN);                       # Form data
        binmode(STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)');  # HTML
        binmode(STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)');  # Error messages
}

my ($q) = ();
my $test = "õäöüžš";
$q = new CGI;

        print $q->header(-type=>"text/html", -charset=>"utf-8"), 
                $q->start_html(-encoding=>"utf-8");

        print "1: ",
                $q->div(  $q->param('text') ),
                "<br />",
                "2: ",
                $q->div( {-id=>"id"},  $q->param('text') ),
                "<br />",
                "3: ",
                $q->div(  $test ),
                "<br />",
                "4: ",
                $q->div( {-id=>"id"},  $test ),
        $q->end_html();
```

It seems to me, that with FastCGI form-data has no utf8-flag on and i don't understand, how to properly force it? Under CGI.pm i declare as:

```
use CGI qw(:all -utf8);
```

But how with FastCGI?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "utf8 flag" at the Perl program level.  If you have incoming data that is utf-8 encoded, you can convert it to a Perl string with the function `Encode::decode_utf8`.  Actually, all text coming into the program must be decoded, with something like `Encode::decode('latin1', $data)` or `Encode::decode('ascii', $data)`.  Raw strings are only for binary data.  See tchrist's and my answers on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default

Comment: @jrockway: therefore i have binmode-lines in BEGIN-block. Because i use CGI with -utf8 flag, i can't apply `:encoding(UTF-8)` for STDIN. CGI.pm decodes form-data (from STDIN and from QUERY_STRING) itself (-utf8 flag). As __chansen__ pointed in answer, binmode may not have effect for FastCGI, but this is certainly over my head ;) Question was about output line no 2, other were fine under CGI and under FastCGI.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) [CGI::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI/Fast.pm) is a subclass of [CGI.pm](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CGI/lib/CGI.pm), so you can specify the same import arguments.

```
use CGI::Fast (-utf8);
```

2) [FCGI](http://search.cpan.org/dist/FCGI/FCGI.PL) streams are implemented using the older stream API, [TIEHANDLE](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html#Tying-FileHandles). Applying PerlIO layers using [binmode()](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html) has no effect. The proper solution would be to encode your data before outputting it, but if thats not an option I can offer this hotpatch:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use CGI::Fast (-utf8);
use FCGI      ();
use Encode    ();

my $enc = Encode::find_encoding('UTF-8');
my $org = \&FCGI::Stream::PRINT;
no warnings 'redefine';
local *FCGI::Stream::PRINT = sub {
    my @OUTPUT = @_;
    for (my $i = 1; $i < @_; $i++) {
        $OUTPUT[$i] = $enc->encode($_[$i], Encode::FB_CROAK|Encode::LEAVE_SRC);
    }
    @_ = @OUTPUT;
    goto $org;
};

my $literal = "õäöüžš";

while (my $q = CGI::Fast->new) {
    print $q->header(-type => "text/html", -charset => "UTF-8"),
          $q->start_html(-encoding => "UTF-8"),
          $q->p("Text 1:" . $literal),
          $q->p("Text 2:" . $q->param('text')),
          $q->end_html;
}
```

Comment: Output of your script: `Text 1:õäöüžš

Text 2:ÃµÃ¤Ã¶Ã¼Å¾Å¡`. Btw, i have no idea, what happened within 6 months (updated system regularly), but now my test script yields "wide character warnings" on 2 prints and dies on 3rd example row (in log i see just: [warn] mod_fcgid: cleanup zombie process #####). When i asked in Feb, only problematic line was 2nd (`$q->div( {-id=>"id"},  $q->param('text') )`) in my script.

Comment: I'm core developer of FCGI and I understand how Perl has implemented support for Unicode. Could you please provide the output of my provided script?

Comment: Versions of FCGI, CGI and Perl would also provide insight.

Comment: Perl 5.10.1, CGI.pm 3.43, FCGI.pm 0.71, CGI::Fast 1.07. Do you need output as HTML? Above is output, which i copied from browser, so second case is scrambled (decoded twice?)

Comment: I can reproduce your issue, you need to upgrade CGI.pm to at-least version 3.47. The "wide character warnings" you see is due to changes in FCGI, thats why i said above that you should encode your data before outputting or use above hotpatch.

Comment: I want to move out from CGI and clean up a legacy code. Your hotpatch makes it more complicated, so there is no motivation to use it in production. I must look for other ways (i already am). Still, it answers my question and was very good insight and i am really greatful for this.

Answer (score 2):

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), Gitweb should fix the issue.

See [commit 2ecfcde](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ecfcdecc612505291cfdffb886b5d7615c3e581) (29 Mar 2020) by [Julien Moutinho (`ju1m`)](https://github.com/ju1m).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 7a8bb6d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7a8bb6db7cc04add05484c4fc907e34f76b12fb9), 22 Apr 2020)</sup>

> ### [`gitweb`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2ecfcdecc612505291cfdffb886b5d7615c3e581): fix UTF-8 encoding when using CGI::Fast
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Julien Moutinho</sup>
>
> FCGI streams are implemented using the older stream API: `TIEHANDLE`, therefore applying `PerlIO` layers using `binmode()` has no effect to them.
>
> The solution in this patch is to **redefine the `FCGI::Stream::PRINT` function to use UTF-8 as output encoding**, except within `git_blob_plain()` and `git_snapshot()` which must still output in raw binary mode.
>
> This problem and solution were previously reported back in 2012:
>
> - Git mailing-list: ["Gitweb running as FCGI does not print its output in UTF-8"](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Gitweb-running-as-FCGI-does-not-print-its-output-in-UTF-8-td7573415.html)
> - [this very page](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5005104/6309)

Answer (score -2):

I would do:

```
use strict;
use CGI;
CGI->compile();
use CGI::Fast;
use utf8;
while (new CGI::Fast) {
    $CGI::PARAM_UTF8=1;# may be this????
    my $q =CGI->new;
    #rest of the code should work
}
```