# Why do I see `á` instead of a space when writing to screen (encoding problem)?

Tags: php, xml, perl, encoding

I am completely lost with encoding issues, I have no idea what's going on, what the problem is exactly and how to fix it.

Basically I'm just trying to read an HTML file from a Zip file, parse it then output pieces to XML. Now something funky is happening with the text I get out of the parser.

When parsing the HTML, instead of a space I get `á` only if I write to the screen. If I keep it in a variable and write to a file it looks fine in the file. However even though it looks right in the XML something is wrong with it, my PHP parser can't parse that XML nor does IE seem to like it.

I had to first `mb_convert_encoding($xmlcontent, "ASCII");` so I could get that XML to parse in PHP.

Any idea what my problem is?

1. extract HTML from a `.tar.gz` file using Perl

   ```
   my $tar = Archive::Tar->new;
   $tar->read("myfile.tar.gz");
   $tar->extract_file('index.html', 'output.html');
   ```
2. load HTML, this is where it starts to get funky, I get output like `Numberáofásourceálines`

   ```
   my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
   $tree->parse_file('output.html') or die $!;
   $tree->elementify;
   ```
3. write to XML

   ```
   my $output = new IO::File(">output.xml");
   my $writer = new XML::Writer(OUTPUT => $output, DATA_MODE => 1,DATA_INDENT => 2);
   ```

Comment: Is your data multi-byte unicode? The strange character smells like it might be. Use a proper character encoding on it.

Comment: You first need to know about the encoding of the input data. Convert it to UTF-8 then.

Comment: how do I determine the encoding? the file is generated automatically from a tool, I have no control over it I can only process it

Comment: Does the HTML have a meta tag defining the character set used? Often it will.

Comment: Show the HTML file. Upload it unchanged somewhere, or provide a hex dump of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I just fixed it by processing this on the html before parsing it, thanks for all the great pointers!

```
s/\&nbsp\;/ /g;
```

Answer (score 2):

If it looks correct when you write it to a file and wrong when you write it to the terminal, it sounds like your terminal is expecting the wrong encoding. Check your terminal settings.'

Also, see Jon Rockway's answer to ["Why does modern Perl avoid UTF-8 by default?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6192088#6192088). With encodings, you have to convert your input to the correct encoding and convert your output to the correct encoding. Everything that looks at the data needs to know which encoding you're using.