# How to create a regexpression for a name with just letters and one "-" i java?

Tags: java, android, regex

I'm trying to validate a name with a regular expression in my android app.

So the rules that I have is; only letters, no spaces or anything (a-ö, A-Ö), and only one hyphen.

I have tried but the reg expression language gives my headaches...

Comment: Read item 41 here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129

Comment: Not sure if you've tried [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) website for regex yet, but it explains pretty well.

Comment: @NullUserException: it's not Perl it is Java. However, this is an easy regexp he's asking for...

Comment: @Khedar I am referring to the sentence that says *"Code that believes someone’s name can only contain certain characters is stupid, offensive, and wrong."*, which I fully endorse.

Comment: Well, I agree, unless said code validates a name in that particular context, a site nickname for example. If you set the rules as "ASCII and hyphens only", that's your right :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that this is the best idea to verify names. But assuming you've settled your requirements, then you can use next example:

```
if(input.matches("[a-zA-Z]+(\\-[a-zA-Z]+)?")) {
    //OK
} else {
    //Invalid
}
```

---

Several examples I've tested using [this page](http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html):

```
String       matches?
qwe            Yes          
qwe-           No   
qwe-qwe        Yes
qwe-qwe-       No   
qw2e-qwe2      No   
qwe-qwe-qwe    No
```

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html gives you the basics.

In particular:

- `[[a-f][0-9]]` shows you can do OR operations.
- `[d-f]` shows you can select ascii ranges

It even tells you:

> Most of the time, the built-in character classes are more useful

and explains the `\w` and `\W` selectors. `\w` accepts underlines and digits.

`[[A-Z][a-z]-]+` should work. The plus is there to ensure you get at least one character, though if you have a user called -, it's not that great imho.

**EDIT:**

If you would add the name of your app, I'd make sure not to buy it though. Such laziness can only lead to an app I don't want to install.