# Data Validation - Regular expression

Tags: regex, spring, validation

I am working on a registration form, where i am providing validation(spring) for input (user)data. 
I have fields like

**Name (Full Name)**

Only Characters are allowed

-> Acceptable values are : 
A, AB, A B, A B C, Abc def, abc def ghi

-> No Junk/special characters are allowed.

- **Regular expression i am currently using :**

  ```
  Pattern.compile("(([a-zA-z])+([\\s]+[\\s])?[^*$&!@%~\",:;{}|=()_0-9])*");
  ```

-> string with single and two spaces are working, which is fine.

-> only numbers not accepting, which is fine.

- **problems**

-> pattern doesn't work with "single character", like "a" or "A"

-> not throwing an error on entering Alphanumeric, like abc23

**Income**

Which should accept strictly only numerical values

- **Regular expression i am currently using :**

  ```
  Pattern.compile ("(([0-9])?[^*&!@%~\",:;{}|=()_a-zA-z])*")
  ```
- **problem**

  accepting alphanumeric

**Registration No**

it can be a character, can be a number, can be aplhanumeric, but no space is allowed

Can anyone please help me in writing the correct regexp (only regexp works) for the above mentioned fields?

Comment: In [tchrist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129)'s words: "Code that believes someone’s name can only contain certain characters is stupid, offensive, and wrong."

Comment: if that's the requirement, you're certainly helpless. tchrist knows this.

Comment: +1 In a previous project, one of our users reported a bug under the title "No Irish Need Apply". You can probably guess what the issue was. Needless to say we were embarrassed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexps are long which leads me to think there may be additional constraints. 
However, given the bullet points you've given...

For the name, you can use:

```
Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z ]+")
```

For income, you can use:

```
Pattern.compile("[0-9]+")
```

For registration, you can use:

```
Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Z0-9]+")
```

Comment: What's considered bad input? I'm not 100% sure what your requirements are. I said that in the post.

Comment: I just tested them. They don't. What language/how are you using them?

Comment: Haha, no worries. I was freaking out for a second as I'm just starting to get into StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks dookehster, I will give it a try. Thanks for your valuable reply. :)

Comment: Thank you very much, dookehster, its working perfectly fine. :)