# Counting number of Unicode characters for MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, unicode

When, in PHP, I have variable that's hold Unicode characters do I need to worry about storing it in MySQL database?

Lets say I have variable value `Dejan Čolić`, I suppose that will for Unicode characters use 2 chars (or 4, I am not sure). Then my variable will be 13/17 chars long in database instead of 11 chars that are firstly specified. Am I right?

If I am right, is there some PHP function that will help count future Unicode characters so I could do proper data validation? Thanks.

Comment: An interesting post on Unicode in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129 (best viewed on Firefox with the [Symbola](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/) font installed)

Comment: Unicode characters have variable length, so they could have 1 to 4 bytes (although UTF-8 allows up to 6 bytes/character)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Characters are characters. 11 characters are 11 characters regardless of the environment. If MySQL doesn't know you are giving it UTF-8 encoded data, it may misinterpret the *bytes* and derive a different character count based on the assumption of a wrong encoding. But if MySQL is made aware of the correct encoding, it'll be 11 *characters*.

It'll be more *bytes* than that though, and even more bytes in MySQL since MySQL is storing UTF-8 data rather inefficiently.

Comment: I my testings `Dejan Čolić` gives 21 and `Dejan Colic` 11? (With both `strlen()` and `mb_strlen()` on GET)

Comment: @Dejan Which encoding is the text in and which encoding does `mb_strlen` *think* the text is in? Try the second `$encoding` parameter of `mb_strlen`.

Comment: @Dejan BTW, reading this may help get a grip on the topic: http://kunststube.net/encoding/

Comment: I made correction and added header. With `utf-8` there are results 13 and 11 (for `Dejan Čolić` and `Dejan Colic`). I suppose that `mb_strlen` think it is `utf-8`..

Comment: `Č` = U+010C and `ć` = U+0107 = both are 2byte charts, so your strlen=13/mb_strlen=11 is perfectly accurate.

Answer (score 2):

PHP: [mb_strlen()](http://php.net/mb_strlen)
MySQL: [CHAR_LENGTH()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_char-length)

Comment: In my tests `mb_strlen()` and `strlen()` are giving same results. Is there any difference?

Comment: strlen() is dumb and counts bytes. mb_strlen is unicode-aware and counts characters. If you're working on an ascii string, then they're the same. Otherwise strlen will over-count.

Comment: Well, then `strlen()` is actually what I need, because MySQL will store characters in bytes length (if there are some chars like `Č`, `ć` etc).  Am I right?

Comment: MySQL'll store the data in whatever charset/collation you specify on the table. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-unicode.html  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/storage-requirements.html