# How to match string with diacritic in perl?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, collation

For example, match "Nation" in ""Îñţérñåţîöñåļîžåţîöñ" without extra modules. Is it possible in new Perl versions (5.14, 5.15 etc)?

> I found an answer! Thanks to **tchrist**

Rigth solution with UCA match (thnx to https://stackoverflow.com/users/471272/tchrist).

```
# found start/end offsets for matched utf-substring (without intersections)
use 5.014;
use strict; 
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Unicode::Collate;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
my $str  = "Îñţérñåţîöñåļîžåţîöñ" x 2;
my $look = "Nation";
my $Collator = Unicode::Collate->new(
    normalization => undef, level => 1
   );

my @match = $Collator->match($str, $look);
if (@match) {
    my $found = $match[0];
    my $f_len  = length($found);
    say "match result: $found (length is $f_len)"; 
    my $offset = 0;
    while ((my $start = index($str, $found, $offset)) != -1) {                                                  
        my $end   = $start + $f_len;
        say sprintf("found at: %s,%s", $start, $end);
        $offset = $end + 1;
    }
}
```

Wrong (but working) solution from http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=485681

> Magic piece of code is:

```
    $str = Unicode::Normalize::NFD($str); $str =~ s/\pM//g;
```

> code example:

```
    use 5.014;
    use utf8;
    use Unicode::Normalize;

    binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
    my $str  = "Îñţérñåţîöñåļîžåţîöñ";
    my $look = "Nation";
    say "before: $str\n";
    $str = NFD($str);
    # M is short alias for \p{Mark} (http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniprops.html)
    $str =~ s/\pM//og; # remove "marks"
    say "after: $str";¬
    say "is_match: ", $str =~ /$look/i || 0;
```

Comment: I don't know if there is any direct support, but you could canonicalize to Fully Decomposed, then strip any characters with a "joining" property (ISTR there is such a property, though not sure what it's called).

Comment: googe "perl remove all diacritics" lots of matches which looks promising

Comment: This is the wrong way to do it.  You need to use a UCA match at level 1.

Comment: See also [Text::Unidecode](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Text::Unidecode)

Comment: @Fredrik: **Except that you can’t do it that way!**  “Removing all diacritics” fails if you want/expect (for example) `smørrebrød` to be matched by  `brod` or for `Óðinn` to be matched by `odin`. With a UCA level-1 match, you *can*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right solution with UCA (thnx to **tchrist**):

```perl
# found start/end offsets for matched s
use 5.014;
use utf8;
use Unicode::Collate;
binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
my $str  = "Îñţérñåţîöñåļîžåţîöñ" x 2;
my $look = "Nation";
my $Collator = Unicode::Collate->new(
    normalization => undef, level => 1
   );

my @match = $Collator->match($str, $look);
say "match ok!" if @match;
```

P.S.
"Code that assumes you can remove diacritics to get at base ASCII letters is evil, still, broken, brain-damaged, wrong, and justification for capital punishment."
© **tchrist** [Why does modern Perl avoid UTF-8 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129)

Answer (score 6):

What do you mean by "without extra modules"?

Here is a solution with `use Unicode::Normalize;` [see on perl doc](http://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode/Normalize.html)

I removed the "ţ" and the "ļ" from your string, my eclipse didn't wanted to save the script with them.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use UTF8;
use Unicode::Normalize;

my $str = "Îñtérñåtîöñålîžåtîöñ";

for ( $str ) {  # the variable we work on
   ##  convert to Unicode first
   ##  if your data comes in Latin-1, then uncomment:
   #$_ = Encode::decode( 'iso-8859-1', $_ );  
   $_ = NFD( $_ );   ##  decompose
   s/\pM//g;         ##  strip combining characters
   s/[^\0-\x80]//g;  ##  clear everything else
 }

if ($str =~ /nation/) {
  print $str . "\n";
}
```

The output is

> Internationaliation

The "ž" is removed from the string, it seems not to be a composed character.

The code for the for loop is from this side [How to remove diacritic marks from characters](http://ahinea.com/en/tech/accented-translate.html)

Another interesting read is [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) from Joel Spolsky

**Update:**

As @tchrist pointed out, there is a algorithm existing, that is better suited, called UCA (Unicode Collation Algorithm). @nordicdyno, already provided a implementation in his question.

The algorithm is described here [Unicode Technical Standard #10, Unicode Collation Algorithm](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/)

the perl module is described here on [perldoc.perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/Unicode/Collate.html#DESCRIPTION)

Comment: Thanks! In my environment "ž" wasn't removed and all works fine. (vim + Mac OS X + perl 5.14.0)

Comment: This is not the way to do this. You want a level-1 UCA match, which is at the primary strength only and therefore ignores diacritics.

Comment: @tchrist I already learned a lot from you regarding unicode from your answers and comments (thanks for that), but I think not enough, yet. To be honest I have no idea what you mean with your comment. (What is UCA standing for?)

Comment: @tchrist: I will be thankful to you if you could look into this, and suggest a solution or a workaround. Our friends from PerlMonks havne't solved it yet, either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13209474/why-is-my-perl-program-failing-with-tiefile-and-unicode-utf-8-encoding