# Levenshtein algorithm in MySql and accented characters

Tags: mysql, utf-8, ascii, levenshtein-distance

I use the Levenshtein plugin  for MySQL from: http://samjlevy.com/2011/03/MySQL-levenshtein-and-damerau-levenshtein-udfs/

I'm trying a query like:

```
SELECT name FROM database WHERE levenshtein(name, 'testć')
```

the problem is that levenshtein function doesnt handle accented characters. I need levenshtein to recognize characters like "C" and "Ć" (and others accented) as the same. So i decided to replace all of it in MySQL, but cant find any function for that. Like:

```
SELECT name FROM database WHERE levenshtein(toAscii(name), toAscii('testć'))
```

I dont want to use something like `REPLACE( REPLACE(name, "ś", "s"), "ć", "c" )`; It may be slow and it looks horrible.

Comment: It isn't really correct to "strip" accents. Accented glyphs are different characters, and a simple transliteration will mangle words.  The correct substitution depends on the language and sometimes the individual word. The best way to do this is via a substitution dictionary. While this SO is about Perl, the principles and comments apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7429964/how-to-match-string-with-diacritic-in-perl

Comment: @tchrist Awoogah, Awooga, code trying to "strip" accents ahoy