# Get diff match percentage for a document against an entire repository (C#)

Tags: c#, algorithm, diff

I have a repository of documents, say in txt format.

When I add a new document to the repository I want to check if there is an existing document in the repository that matches the one I am inserting.

If the match is above X% (90%?) I can ask the user if they want to continue or update the existing document.
There are ways to get the diff percentage, for example: [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19089666/how-to-calculate-similarity-with-google-diff-match-patch-c-sharp-library)

But I need to diff the new document against all the documents in the repository.

Does anyone have a clue how can I check the entire repository very fast so the user doesn't have to wait?

Thank you

Comment: OK, I've changed the format to txt to focus on the problem at hand: How to "match percentage" of a document vs an entire repository quickly

Answer (score 0):

If you vectorize your documents using sentence to vector techniques (using skipgram or COBW in fasttext), then you can index the vectors using HNSw index in fasttext to find the similar documents to the query document in the repository very fast.