# Remove accents from accented characters

Tags: perl

I am looking for advice what library and/or function should I use to convert international text to it's English characters alternative.

For example

```
Vous avez aimé l'épée offerte par les elfes à Frodon
```

convert into

```
Vous avez aime l'epee offerte par les elfes a Frodon
```

Comment: @Janos - I am using `unidecode` now, but I got wrong results. For example `Etüde` is for some reason converted into `EtA1_4de`

Comment: I see what you mean. You should add that in your question. Btw I cannot reproduce your issue, unidecode does work for me.

Comment: @Ωmega, You did `unidecode(encode_utf8("Et\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}de"))` instead of `unidecode("Et\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}de")`.

Comment: Trying to remove accents is almost always the wrong thing to do. I guess you want to: [How to match string with diacritic in perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7429964)

Comment: @ikegami - I don't use `encode_utf8`, but it may come already encoded. Should I decode it somehow before `unidecode` is used?

Comment: @Ωmega, and I'm sure you don't use `\N{}` either. You missed the point. You did the equivalent of those. Yes, you should. `unidecode` expects text, not UTF-8.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

First you can decompose the characters using [Unicode::Normalize](https://metacpan.org/module/Unicode::Normalize), then you can use a simple regex to delete all the diacriticals. (I think simply grabbing all the non-spacing mark characters should do it, but there might be an obscure exception or two.)

Here's an example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

use Unicode::Normalize;

my $test = "Vous avez aimé l'épée offerte par les elfes à Frodon";

my $decomposed = NFKD( $test );
$decomposed =~ s/\p{NonspacingMark}//g;

print $decomposed;
```

Output:

```
Vous avez aime l'epee offerte par les elfes a Frodon
```

Comment: `Etüde` >> `EtA1_4de` :-/

Comment: Interesting, never thought about the `NonspacingMark`. The usual approach is the 'dictionary attack'... does this not presuppose that all such characters are composed though? Maybe I need to look at what `NFKD` does.

Comment: @Ωmega, I don't get that result for Etüde. Are you `encode`ing your output?

Comment: @Ωmega, You changed something else too, because you passed the UTF-8 of `Etüde` rather than `Etüde`.

Comment: I get an extra "%" at the end of the string.