# Javascript function using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created a function using reg-ex to validate a field in JavaScript. My function is

```
//FIRST NAME VALIDATION
var strFilter = /^[A-Za-z]*$/;
var fname = document.getElementById('fname');
fname = fname.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');

if ( ( !strFilter.test(fname.value) ) || fname == '') { 
    alert("Please enter a valid first name\r\n (only characters)");
    document.getElementById('fname').style.background = '#DFE32D';
    document.getElementById('fname').focus();
    document.getElementById('fname').value = '';
    return false;
}
```

Issue with the function is, it is taking `stackoverflow234232` also as true. I want to constrain it for character only.

Comment: `/^[A-Za-z]*$/.test("stackoverflow234232")` yields `false` for me.

Comment: From [tchrist's post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129): "Code that believes someone’s name can only contain certain characters is stupid, offensive, and wrong."

Comment: /^[A-Za-z]*$/.test("stackoverflow234232") returns false actually.

Comment: Agree with both comments, works for me but what happens when "Renée" tries to enter her name.

Comment: If it would returns false I won't put the question here.... I can show you live example.... `http://www.oxfordmontessori.com/register-user.php`. Visit the link enter first name... this is js for that field...

Comment: @Godwin Or Daniel O'Higgins. Or Omar al-Bashir. etc. etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is on this line -

```
if ((!strFilter.test(fname.value)) || fname == '') {
```

it should be -

```
if ((!strFilter.test(fname) ) || fname == '') {
```

`fname` is a string variable by the time you get to the if statement, so `fname.value` is returning `undefined` and the call to `test` is not working.

Comment: Whats the difference between both. Because I think in both cases it takes value....

Comment: @Rahul No, it does not. You make `fname` a string on the previous line. You cannot access the original HTMLElement after that.

Comment: @Rahul If you have `var hello = 'hello';` then `console.log(hello);` will return 'hello' but  
`console.log(hello.value);` will return `undefined` as hello has no `value` property. Even though `fname` starts as a textbox object it gets converted to a string on this line `fname = fname.value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');`

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/fHUYe/9/) instead

```
<!--   FIRST NAME VALIDATION   -->
var strFilter = /^[A-Za-z]*$/;
var fname = $('#fname');
fname.val(fname.val().replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,''));


if ( ( !strFilter.test(fname.val()) ) || fname == '') {
    alert("Please enter a valid first name\r\n (only characters)");
    $('#fname').css('background-color','#DFE32D');
    $('#fname').focus();
    $('#fname').val('');
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The OP did not say he's using jQuery. But nevertheless you could chain the `$("#fname")` calls.