# How does Perl multiple-line regex matching interact with Unicode character properties?

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I am processing a multiple-line string, with Unix (\n) line breaks.

Some of its lines have the form "A, a" (i.e. upper-case letter, comma, space, lower-case letter), and I want to delete those from the string.

I can accomplish this with a regex replacement, but there is a mystery that I don't understand:

A regex that uses "[A-Z]" and "[a-z]" works in both normal mode and multiple-line mode.

A regex that uses "\p{Lu}" and "\p{Ll}" works, but only in normal mode, NOT in multiple-line mode.

EACH OF THESE SUCCEEDS:

```
$all =~ s/\n\K *[A-Z], [a-z]\n//g;    # 1

$all =~ s/^ *[A-Z], [a-z]\n//mg;      # 2

$all =~ s/\n\K *\p{Lu}, \p{Ll}\n//g;  # 3
```

BUT THIS FAILS:

```
$all =~ s/^ *\p{Lu}, \p{Ll}\n//mg;    # 4
```

I expected the /m switch to change the meaning of "^" in the regex, but nothing else. So, I expected statement 4 to work, just like statements 1, 2, and 3. Statement 2 seems to show that the multiple-line syntax is OK, and Statement 3 seems to show that the Unicode character properties match as expected, so, when I combine these, I expect statement 4 to work.

I have looked at Tom Christensen's answer [Why does modern Perl avoid UTF-8 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129), but I don't see anything there about multiple-line regex matching, nor have I found an answer elsewhere.

Comment: Give an example where the outcome of #2 and #4 is different. My test, `$all = "foo\n  A, x\nmeow";`, has the same outcome for both.

Answer (score 3):

I cannot replicate your problem.

```
$ perl -wle'
   $all = "foo\n  A, x\nmeow";
   $all =~ s/^ *[A-Z], [a-z]\n//mg;
   print $all;
'
foo
meow

$ perl -wle'
   $all = "foo\n  A, x\nmeow";
   $all =~ s/^ *\p{Lu}, \p{Ll}\n//mg;
   print $all;
'
foo
meow
```

Tested with 5.8.8, 5.10.1, 5.12.4 (threaded) and 5.16.0 on Linux.

Best guess: `pos($all)` isn't zero. Perhaps you did something silly like `if ($all =~ /.../g)`.

---

I couldn't reproduce with the spaces removed either at first.

```
$ perl -wle'
   $all = "foo\nA, x\nmeow";
   $all =~ s/^ *[A-Z], [a-z]\n//mg;
   print $all;
'
foo
meow

$ perl -wle'
   $all = "foo\n  A, x\nmeow";
   $all =~ s/^ *\p{Lu}, \p{Ll}\n//mg;
   print $all;
'
foo
meow
```

Tested with 5.10.1 (threaded) on cygwin.

```
>perl -wle"$all = qq{foo\nA, x\nmeow}; $all =~ s/^ *[A-Z], [a-z]\n//mg; print $all;"
foo
meow

>perl -wle"$all = qq{foo\nA, x\nmeow}; $all =~ s/^ *\p{Lu}, \p{Ll}\n//mg; print $all;"
foo
meow
```

Tested with 5.14.0 (threaded) and 5.14.2 (threaded) on Windows (ActivePerl).

BUT, AHA!!!!

```
>perl -wle"$all = qq{foo\nA, x\nmeow}; $all =~ s/^ *[A-Z], [a-z]\n//mg; print $all;"
foo
meow

>perl -wle"$all = qq{foo\nA, x\nmeow}; $all =~ s/^ *\p{Lu}, \p{Ll}\n//mg; print $all;"
foo
A, x
meow
```

Tested with 5.10.1 (threaded), 5.12.1 (threaded) and 5.12.4 (threaded) on Windows (ActivePerl).

There seems to be a bug in older versions of Perl. It appears to have been fixed in 5.14. The bug appears to be in the optimiser (as seen with `-Mre=debug`), so it can be bypassed by "disabling" the optimiser.

```
>perl -wle"$all = qq{foo\nA, x\nmeow}; $all =~ s/^ *\p{Lu}, \p{Ll}\n//mg; print $all;"
foo
A, x
meow

>perl -wle"$all = qq{foo\nA, x\nmeow}; $all =~ s/^ *\p{Lu}{1}, \p{Ll}\n//mg; print $all;"
foo
meow
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid comment. I have replicated your result (with 5.12.4). However, if I remove the 2 spaces to the left of "A, x" in both scripts, then they behave differently: The first succeeds, and the second fails.

Comment: @user1572601: I've tried all 4 regexes on `"foo\nA, x\nmeow"` and all gave the same (expected) result. (Perl l5.14.2)

Comment: @MRAB, See update. Includes a workaround for this bug apparently fixed in newer versions of Perl.