# Perl regular expression matching on large Unicode code points

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, encoding

I am trying to replace various characters with either a single quote or double quote.

Here is my test file:

```
# Replace all with double quotes
＂ fullwidth
“ left
” right
„ low
" normal

# Replace all with single quotes
' normal
‘ left
’ right
‚ low
‛ reverse
` backtick
```

I'm trying to do this...

```
perl -Mutf8 -pi -e "s/[\x{2018}\x{201A}\x{201B}\x{FF07}\x{2019}\x{60}]/'/ug" test.txt
perl -Mutf8 -pi -e 's/[\x{FF02}\x{201C}\x{201D}\x{201E}]/"/ug' text.txt
```

But only the backtick character gets replaced properly. I think it has something to do with the other code points being too large, but I cannot find any documentation on this.

Here I have a [one-liner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-liner_program) which dumps the Unicode code points, to verify they match my regular expression.

```
$ awk -F\  '{print $1}' test.txt | \
    perl -C7 -ne 'for(split(//)){print sprintf("U+%04X", ord)." ".$_."\n"}'

U+FF02 ＂
U+201C “
U+201D ”
U+201E „
U+0022 "

U+0027 '
U+2018 ‘
U+2019 ’
U+201A ‚
U+201B ‛
U+0060 `
```

Why isn't my regular expression matching?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It isn’t matching because you forgot the `-CSAD`  in your call to Perl, and don’t have `$PERL_UNICODE` set in your environment.  You have only said `-Mutf8` to announce that your source code is in that encoding.  This does not affect your I/O.

You need:

```
$ perl -CSAD -pi.orig -e "s/[\x{2018}\x{201A}\x{201B}\x{FF07}\x{2019}\x{60}]/'/g" test.txt
```

I do mention this sort of thing in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129) a couple of times.

Comment: @tchrist, please correct your answer by replacing -CSAD with -CSD.  I do not have the editing powers to do so.

Comment: @HansDeragon  Done.

Answer (score 8):

With `use utf8;`, you told Perl your source code is UTF-8. This is useless (though harmless) since you've limited your source code to ASCII.

With `/u`, you told Perl to use the Unicode definitions of `\s`, `\d`, `\w`. This is useless (though harmless) since you don't use any of those patterns.

You did not decode your input, so your inputs consists solely of bytes, so most of the characters in your class (e.g. `\x{2018}`) can't possibly match anything. You need to decode your input (and of course, encode your output). Using `-CSD` will likely do this.

```
perl -CSD -i -pe'
   s/[\x{2018}\x{201A}\x{201B}\x{FF07}\x{2019}\x{60}]/\x27/g;
   s/[\x{FF02}\x{201C}\x{201D}\x{201E}]/"/g;
' text.txt
```

Comment: I hate having to figure out how to quote things in the shell. I usually just opt for the `\x27` trick instead.

Comment: I just did `'` ⇒ `'\''` without thinking, buy yeah, `'` ⇒ `\x27` is a good idea.

Comment: I think you mean "need to decode you **input**", and probably also then "need to encode your output".

Comment: @tchirst, Typo fixed. Addition added.