# UTF-8 vs. ASCII-8BIT Encoding Inconsistency in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, encoding, utf-8, ruby-on-rails-3.1, i18n-gem

I know there are many questions about rails and encoding out there, but I haven't been able to find anything about this specific question.

I have a Ruby on Rails application using `rails 3.1.3` and running under `Jruby 1.6.7`. We have support for both English and French - and we use the `I18n` library/gem to accomplish this.

Sample translation file parts:

```
#---- config/locales/en.yml ----
en:
  button_label_verify: "Verify"

#---- config/locales/fr.yml ----
fr:
  button_label_verify: "Vérifier"
```

In certain cases I am getting the following encoding error:

```
Internal Server Error: Encoding::CompatibilityError incompatible character encodings: UTF-8 and ASCII-8BIT
```

**Case 1:**

```
#---- app/views/_view_page.html.erb ----
.....
<h3><%= get_button_label() %></h3>
....

#---- app/helpers/page_helper.rb ----
def get_button_label
    return I18n.t(:button_label_verify)
end
```

This works - there are no encoding errors and translations between French and English work just fine.

**Case 2:**

```
#---- app/views/_view_page.html.erb ----
.....
<h3><%= get_button_label() %></h3>
....

#---- app/helpers/page_helper.rb ----
def get_button_label
    return "#{I18n.t(:button_label_verify)}"
end
```

This however does not work. The only difference is the value being returned includes strings with computed code *in* the string as opposed to something like

```
return "string " + I18n.t(:button_label_verify)
```

*Note:* The above causes no errors either - the encoding issue is only when the computed I18n translation is **in** the quotes.

**Case 3:**

```
#---- app/views/_view_page.html.erb ----
.....
<h3><%= "#{I18n.t(:button_label_verify)}" %></h3>
....
```

This causes no error... so the problem seems to somehow be related to the dynamic code (with French characters) within the string, on top of printing out a string returned from a helper function.

I know how to work around this/fix it - but what I am wondering is if anyone can provide some insight into why it is this way - is it this way for any good reason? IMO, when you get to low level - printing out a string is printing out a string, so I don't understand how one way causes and error and another way doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Putting

```
#encoding: utf-8
```

at the top of your files containing ascii-extended  characters should fix encoding related issues (at elast the one coming from project files ...)

I couldn't tell why it doesn't work on a helper when using interpolation though ...

Comment: Hey Anthony - thanks for the reply! We've tried this many many times (putting `#encoding: utf-8` at the top of those files... and the problem still happens. I think this is because the files themselves don't actually contain the extended characters (those are in the YAML files) - but then the extended characters are getting computed into a ruby string - and that seems to be the issue

Comment: Yeah, I meant, you have to put this in the yaml file, not the helper ... did you try that also?

Comment: Yup! That has always been there :)

Comment: We have also added the following which made no difference (in environment.rb): `Encoding.default_external = Encoding::UTF_8
    Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8`

Comment: I just tried in one of my app and it works flawlessly, but, I'n MRI 1.9.3 ... could be jRuby specific ...

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip!! Though we need to run in Jruby for production I will try switching my development mode over to Ruby - I am curious to see if it is Jruby - and I wonder if the new Jruby 1.7 would fix it... I have a workaround for production since I can make it work... however I am extremely curious! Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah it's an interesting problem ... tell me if you find out :)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need to set the KCODE environment variable for the file (this is important for ruby 1.8 compatibility):

```
# encoding: UTF-8
$KCODE = 'UTF8' unless RUBY_VERSION >= '1.9'
```

It could also be that your files are not encoded in UTF-8. For that you need more than just the plaintext header. In Eclipse it is hidden under *Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Spelling* and for Notepad and most Windows programs when when you *Save As* the file. The `enca` command is one way of doing it on Linux but I'm sure there are others. I can't count the times I have seen a file say it is UTF-8 but it is actually some other encoding because UTF-8 functions like ASCII for 8-bit characters so you don't often notice the problem until you check the headers in a HEX editor.

Please take some time to read about file encoding:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html)
- [Why perl doesn't use UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129)
- [Every character has a story #4: U+feff (alternate title: UTF-8 is the BOM, dude!)](http://www.siao2.com/2005/01/20/357028.aspx)

This is incredibly important to get right and it can save you a lot of pain later when you port to East Asian languages (you should always plan to do this!)