# regex_match for names

Tags: php, regex

I have validation on first and last name like so

```
regex_match[/^[a-zA-Z \'-()]{0,25}+$/]
```

Are there any characters I am missing? how do I know what characters are exceptable for first and last name.

or is there a regex_match for names?

Comment: Please do not use signatures/taglines in your posts. Your user box counts as your signature, and you can use your profile to post any information about yourself you like. [FAQ on signatures/taglines](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Comment: People like Alonso Pérez and Björn Borg would not be pleased with your validation routine. And heavens forbid if the person has a name longer than 25 characters. To paraphrase [Tom Christiansen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/396458): code that believes someone’s name can only contain certain characters (and/or a certain amount of characters) is stupid, offensive, and wrong. Also read: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
regex_match[^[A-Z]'?[- a-zA-Z]( [a-zA-Z])*$]
```

If you need to go for a name like Jérémie O'Co-nor

Try this

```
regex_match[^([ \u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'\-])+$]
```

Comment: this [^([ \u00c0-\u01ffa-zA-Z'\-])+$] allowes $...which is not in a name.