# Treat arguments as UTF-8 encoded?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8, command-line-arguments

I've read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/) and I generally try to follow the ideas from Toms answer, but I have a problem with one thing.

How can I write my program so that it will treat command line arguments as UTF8 encoded?

It looks that I have two options:

- use -CA option to perl
- use PERL5OPTS env variable.

The problem is that I write my perl programs with shebang:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
```

as perl is in different locations on various systems I'm using.

This means - I can't use -CA option (or I don't know how, as `#!/usr/bin/env perl -CA` doesn't work.

I would also prefer to avoid having to specify special env vars before calling the script.

Is my only hope "manual" decoding of @ARGV, like:

```
use Encode;
@ARGV = map { decode( 'utf8', $_ ) } @ARGV;
```

or is there some better/nicer way?