# When and how might the operating system store a file under a different name than I gave it?

Tags: unicode, language-agnostic, compatibility, robustness

I found this statement [under another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129) concerning Unicode and I'd like to ask for further elaboration of this rather surprising fact.

> 47. Code that believes once you successfully create a file by a given name, that when you run ls or readdir on its enclosing directory,
>       you'll actually find that file with the name you created it under is
>       buggy, broken, and wrong. Stop being surprised by this!

When does this happen and what to do about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example which comes to my mind: If you create a file under OSX that is named `é` (single `U+00E9` codepoint), the OS will store it actually as `U+0065 U+0301` (Unicode decomposition). The file will be still accessible under the original name, but listed as decomposed.

How to avoid: don't lookup your files manually unless you are sure their names are pure ASCII.

Second: On Windows, if you have a file called `e`, try creating (with overwriting enabled) a file called `E`, the OS will still list a file called `e`. If `e` didn't exists beforehand, a file called `E` would be created.

How to avoid: don't lookup your files manually unless you are sure their names are pure ASCII, and take case into account. Try using a consistent capitalisation style. I suggest going all lowercase.

Third: on Windows, if for example you have Windows 1250 as your system encoding, and you want to create a file named `ê` via the narrow, char-based API, a file called `e` will be created instead. This of course is easy to avoid, but this exact problem bit me once: WinRAR extracted files `ê.png`, `è.png` and `e.png` all into `e.png`, overwriting data. Similar problems can happen with other encoding mixups, too.

How to avoid: don't use API's that take the filename as a `char*` on Windows.