# remove accents with perl, using tr operator

Tags: perl, unicode, ascii

I am trying to remove accents from my text by running on it a perl script, in which I use the tr operator (the simpler method I found):

I tried:

```
tr/àâäéèëêîïôöûùüç/aaaeeeeiioouuuc/;
```

It removes accents, but I get the character 'aa' instead of 'a', 'ae' instead of 'e', etc..

Comment: Can you show us the input string producing weird output ?

Answer (score 7):

Better to use a proper module like [`Text::Undiacritic`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::Undiacritic) =)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
binmode(STDIN, ":utf8");
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
binmode(STDERR, ":utf8");

use Text::Undiacritic qw(undiacritic);

my $string = "C'est l'été à Paris ?\n";
print undiacritic $string;
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
C'est l'ete a Paris ?
```

#### NOTE

As far as you asked string with accent, `undiacritic()` will work removing *accents*, but will not work by example on [typographic ligature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographic_ligature). If you pass the string

```
C'est l'été à Paris Lætitia ?
```

it will not substitute `æ`

Welcome in the real tricky world: Unicode-UTF8. [A good pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default/6163129#6163129)

Comment: sounds to me like he has utf8 data not marked as such; can you address that part?