# How to achieve fool proof unicode handling in Perl CGI?

Tags: perl, unicode

So I have a mysql database which is serving an old wordpress db I backed up.  I am writing some simple perl scripts to serve the wordpress articles (I don't want a wordpress install).

Wordpress for whatever reason stored all quotes as unicode chars, all ... as unicode chars, all double dashes, all apostrophes, there is unicode nbsp all over the place -- it is a mess (this is why I do not a wordpress install).

In my test environment, which is Linux Mint 17.1 Perl 5.18.2 Mysql 5.5, things mostly work fine when I have Content-type line being served up with "charset=utf-8" (except apostrophes just simply never decode properly no matter what combination I of things I try).  Omitting the charset causes all unicode characters to break (except apostrophes now work).  This is OK, with the exception of the apostrophes, I under stand what is going on and I have a handle on the data.

Now on my production environment, which is a VM, is Linux CentOS 6.5 Perl 5.10.1 Mysql 5.6.22, and here things do not work at all.  Whether or not I include the "charset=utf-8" in the Content-type there is no difference, no unicode charatcers work correctly (including apostrophes).  Maybe it has to do with the lower version of Perl?  Does anyone have any insight?

Apart from this very specific case, does anyone know of a fool-proof Perl idiom for handling unicode which comes from the DB?  (I'm not sure where in the pipeline things are going wrong, but I have a suspicion it is at the DB-driver level)

One of the problems is that my data is very inconsistent and dirty.  I *could* parse the entire DB and scrub all unicode and re-import it -- the point is I want to avoid that.  I want a one-size fits all collection of Perl scripts for reading wordpress databases.

Comment: maybe add the DBD::mysql versions for test and production?

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default

Comment: Which exact bytes are the apostrophes? Perhaps the data is in another encoding than UTF8.

Comment: In general, Unicode is an abstract concept, you can't get Unicode from the DB -- actual data is always encoded.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich in response to "which exact bytes are the apostrophes" : I'm not sure.  They look 'weird' to me, I could inspect closer and find out but a solution posted bellow works so I am just going to move on.  Some backround: I was not involved in the maintenence of this wordpress site when it was running years ago -- but I believe whoever did manage the site entered the article content via copy-pasting from a pdf ... so there are countless character anomolies which can exist at any time.

Comment: From the database: "Ho Ho Ho’s And Christmas Clothes, ‘Tis The Season To Hit the Malls!"  In that sentence alone there are two different types of unicode apostrophes ... so you see what kind of mess I am working with...

Comment: Yes, they are probably "smart quotes" that Windows likes to use instead of the simple ASCII ', and they usually mean the encoding is Windows-1252, not UTF8. But then the other characters wouldn't have converted correctly using UTF8, so I was wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dealing with Perl and UTF-8 has been a pain to me. After a good amount of time i learned that there is no "fool proof unicode handling" in Perl ... but there is an unicode handling that can be of help:

The Encode module.

As the perlunifaq says (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html):

> When should I decode or encode?
>
> Whenever you're communicating text with anything that is external to
>   your perl process, like a database, a text file, a socket, or another
>   program. Even if the thing you're communicating with is also written
>   in Perl.

So we do this to every UTF-8 text string sent to our Perl process:

```
my $perl_str = decode('utf8',$myExt_str);
```

And this to every text string sent from Perl to anything external to our Perl process:

```
my $ext_str = encode('utf8',$perl_str);
```

...

Now that's a lot of encoding/decoding when we retrieve or send data from/to a mysql or postgresql database. But fear not, because there is a way to tell Perl that EVERY TEXT STRING from/to a database are utf8. Additionally we tell the database that every text string should be treated as UTF-8. The only downside is that you need to be sure that every text string is UTF-8 encoded... but that's another story:

```
# For MySQL:
# This requires DBD::mysql version 4 or greater
use DBI;
my $dbh = DBI->connect ('dbi:mysql:test_db',
    $username,
    $password,
    {mysql_enable_utf8 => 1}
);
```

Ok, now we have the text strings from our database in utf8 and the database knows all our text strings should be treated as UTF-8... But what about anything else? We need to tell Perl (AND CGI) that EVERY TEXT STRING we write in our process is utf8 AND tell other other processes to treat our text strings as UTF-8 as well:

```
use utf8;
use CGI '-utf8';

my $cgi = new CGI;
$cgi->charset('UTF-8');
```

## UPDATED!

> What is a "wide character"?
>
> This is a term used both for characters with an ordinal value greater
>   than 127, characters with an ordinal value greater than 255, or any
>   character occupying more than one byte, depending on the context. The
>   Perl warning "Wide character in ..." is caused by a character with an
>   ordinal value greater than 255.
>
> With no specified encoding layer, Perl
>   tries to fit things in ISO-8859-1 for backward compatibility reasons.
>   When it can't, it emits this warning (if warnings are enabled), and
>   outputs UTF-8 encoded data instead. To avoid this warning and to avoid
>   having different output encodings in a single stream, always specify
>   an encoding explicitly, for example with a PerlIO layer:

```
# The next line is required to avoid the "Wide character in print" warning
# AND to avoid having different output encodings in a single stream.
binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";
```

...

Even with all of this sometimes you need to encode('utf8',$perl_str) . That's why i learn there is no fool proof unicode handling in Perl. Please read the perlunifaq (http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunifaq.html)

I hope this helps.

Comment: {mysql_enable_utf8 => 1} seemed to do the trick!  Even apostrophes are working now!  Thank you very much.

Comment: followup question: I like "use utf8", the way my scripts work is there is one class definition file which is included in each of the various scripts at the top.  is it enough for the include file to have "use ut88" or does each individual script also require this declaration?

Comment: although everything is renderring more perfect than i have ever seen before now, i am beginging to see some warning output (in my logs, not my pages) "Wide character in print at ..." .  How concerned should I be here?  I'm under the impression this is a non-issue, because with utf-8 in the HTTP Content-type, even if a wide character is print by perl the web client should understand how to decode it.  Am I wrong?

Comment: Every script that writes text strings (like `my $str = "ñáä"; print $str;`) requires `use utf8;` if you want Perl to know those text strings are utf8. I put `use utf8;` everywhere just to be safe.

I forgot to mention:  `binmode STDOUT, ":encoding(UTF-8)";` is required to avoid the _"Wide character in print ..."_ warning. I'll update my answer.