# Perl | IMAP folder encoding. UTF8 -> UTF7 -> UTF8 = fail

Tags: perl, utf-8

I need advice for imap folder encoding.

I am created by my mail client (Thunderbird) imap folder with russian symbols.

Folder name is - **Проверка**

Folder name on filesystem is - **user.mylogin.&BB8EQAQ+BDIENQRABDoEMA-**

I wrote this code for convert (perl v5.10.1)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Encode::IMAPUTF7;

my $folder=$ARGV[1];

binmode(STDOUT,':utf8');

if ($ARGV[0] eq 'to')
    { print Encode::IMAPUTF7::encode('IMAP-UTF-7', $folder) }
    elsif ($ARGV[0] eq 'from')
    { print Encode::IMAPUTF7::decode('IMAP-UTF-7', $folder) }
print "\n";
```

Try convert folder name to russian

```
[w@pandora6 tmp]$ ./imapfolder.pl from '&BB8EQAQ+BDIENQRABDoEMA-'
Проверка
```

All work fine

Try reverse convert

```
[w@pandora6 tmp]$ ./imapfolder.pl to Проверка
&ANAAnwDRAIAA0AC+ANAAsgDQALUA0QCAANAAugDQALA-
```

Hmm.. i am expect **&BB8EQAQ+BDIENQRABDoEMA-**

Ok, encode back

```
[w@pandora6 tmp]$ ./imapfolder.pl from '&ANAAnwDRAIAA0AC+ANAAsgDQALUA0QCAANAAugDQALA-'
ÐÑÐ¾Ð²ÐµÑÐºÐ°
```

WTF? I expected **Проверка**

What went wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have been caught by one of the [many gotchas of Unicode in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/14660).  `use utf8` *only* turns on UTF-8 syntax.  That means things like *constant* strings, variable names and function names will be in UTF-8.  Everything else will not.  Specifically the strings in `@ARGV` will not be UTF-8.  Those will still be plain bytes.

Fortunately there is a simple fix. Use [utf8::all](https://metacpan.org/pod/utf8::all).  This will turn on all of the UTF-8 features you'd expect `use utf8` to do.

- Makes @ARGV encoded in UTF-8 (when utf8::all is used from the main package).
- Filehandles are opened with UTF-8 encoding turned on by default (including STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR). If you don't want UTF-8 for a particular filehandle, you'll have to set binmode $filehandle.
- charnames are imported so \N{...} sequences can be used to compile Unicode characters based on names.
- readdir now returns UTF-8 characters instead of bytes.
- glob and the <> operator now return UTF-8 characters instead of bytes.

Your code is reduced to...

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8::all;
use Encode::IMAPUTF7;

my $folder=$ARGV[1];

if ($ARGV[0] eq 'to') {
    print Encode::IMAPUTF7::encode('IMAP-UTF-7', $folder)
}
elsif ($ARGV[0] eq 'from') {
    print Encode::IMAPUTF7::decode('IMAP-UTF-7', $folder)
}
print "\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `utf8::all` installed and just want a quick one-liner, you can also use [Perl's `-C` option](https://perldoc.perl.org/5.30.0/perlrun#-C-%5Bnumber/list%5D) to make it do everything in UTF8.

Example:

```sh
$ utf7=$(perl -CSA -MEncode::IMAPUTF7 -le 'print Encode::IMAPUTF7::encode("IMAP-UTF-7", shift)' "Проверка")
$ echo "$utf7"
&BB8EQAQ+BDIENQRABDoEMA-

$ perl -CSA -MEncode::IMAPUTF7 -le 'print Encode::IMAPUTF7::decode("IMAP-UTF-7", shift)' "$utf7"
Проверка
```

Comment: How to create a pipe with this command please? perl -CSA -MEncode::IMAPUTF7 -le 'print Encode::IMAPUTF7::encode("IMAP-UTF-7", shift)' "Проверка" echo "string" | perl...