# Why does [^\w] match some word characters but not [^\p{Word}]?

Tags: perl, character-class

I've written a Perl script that prints out characters matching a Unicode property. It seems to work all right for most properties so far.

But it prints out `ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöøùúûüýþ
ÿ` among characters matching `[^\w]`. These characters should rather match `\w`. Strangely enough, they match `\p{Word}`.

I've tried without success:

- `map { decode ( "UTF-8", $_ ) }`
- `map { pack 'U0C*', unpack 'C*', $_ }`

How can I make `[^\w]` not match those word characters?

#### chars.pl

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;

binmode STDOUT, ':utf8';

my $c;
my $cols = 80;
my $arg = shift;
my $regex = qr/$arg/;

for ( map { chr } 0x20 .. 0xFFFF )
{
  next if /\p{Unassigned}|\p{NChar}|\p{Cs}/;

  if ( $_ =~ $regex )
  {
    print STDOUT;
    print STDOUT "\n" if ++$c % $cols == 0;
  }

}

print STDOUT "\n" if defined $c and $c % $cols != 0;
exit 0;
```

Good:

```
$ ./chars.pl '\p{Cyrillic}'
ЀЁЂЃЄЅІЇЈЉЊЋЌЍЎЏАБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЪЫЬЭЮЯабвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщъыьэюя
ѐёђѓєѕіїјљњћќѝўџѠѡѢѣѤѥѦѧѨѩѪѫѬѭѮѯѰѱѲѳѴѵѶѷѸѹѺѻѼѽѾѿҀҁ҂҃҄҇ҊҋҌҍҎҏҐґҒғҔҕҖҗҘҙҚқҜҝҞҟҠҡ
ҢңҤҥҦҧҨҩҪҫҬҭҮүҰұҲҳҴҵҶҷҸҹҺһҼҽҾҿӀӁӂӃӄӅӆӇӈӉӊӋӌӍӎӏӐӑӒӓӔӕӖӗӘәӚӛӜӝӞӟӠӡӢӣӤӥӦӧӨөӪӫӬӭӮӯӰӱ
ӲӳӴӵӶӷӸӹӺӻӼӽӾӿԀԁԂԃԄԅԆԇԈԉԊԋԌԍԎԏԐԑԒԓԔԕԖԗԘԙԚԛԜԝԞԟԠԡԢԣԤԥԦԧᴫᵸⷠⷡⷢⷣⷤⷥⷦⷧⷨⷩⷪⷫⷬⷭⷮⷯⷰⷱⷲⷳⷴⷵⷶⷷ
ⷸⷹⷺⷻⷼⷽⷾⷿꙀꙁꙂꙃꙄꙅꙆꙇꙈꙉꙊꙋꙌꙍꙎꙏꙐꙑꙒꙓꙔꙕꙖꙗꙘꙙꙚꙛꙜꙝꙞꙟꙠꙡꙢꙣꙤꙥꙦꙧꙨꙩꙪꙫꙬꙭꙮ꙯꙰꙱꙲꙳꙼꙽꙾ꙿꚀꚁꚂꚃꚄꚅꚆꚇꚈꚉꚊꚋꚌꚍꚎꚏ
ꚐꚑꚒꚓꚔꚕꚖꚗ
$
```

Good:

```
$ ./chars.pl '[^\p{Word}]' | grep É
$
```

Bad:

```
$ ./chars.pl '[^\w]' | grep É
°±²³´µ¶·¸¹º»¼½¾¿ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖ×ØÙÚÛÜÝÞßàáâãäåæçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõö÷øùúûüýþ
$
```

Perl v5.14.2

Comment: You might be interested in the `unichars` (and `uniprops`) programs which are part of Unicode::Tussle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Unicode support in Perl is huge topic, see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/6600109)

To make `\w` match same as `\p{Word}`, you need to have `/u` character set modifier in effect (available in Perl since version 5.14).

Simplest way is to just start program with

```
use v5.14;
```

which (among other things) enables feature `unicode_strings` and makes all regexes default to `/u` character set modifier. You can also just enable that feature explicitly:

```
use feature 'unicode_strings';
```

Third way is to use `/u` modified in regex to change character set on per-regex basis.

You can read about effects of different regex character set modifiers from [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) manpage. These are `/d`, `/u`, `/a` and `/l`.

The `\w` is explained in [perlrecharclass](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#Backslash-sequences) manpage.