# Cannot split a unicode string without converting to ascii - python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, split, non-ascii-characters

I want to split the string `I have £300` but it seems that the split function first converts it to a ascii and after. But I can't convert it back to unicode the same as it was before.

Is there any other way to split such a unicode string without breaking it as in the snippet bellow.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
mystring = 'I have £300.'
alist = mystring.split()
alist = [item.decode("utf-8") for item in alist]
print "alist",alist
print "mystring.split()",mystring.split()

#I want to get [I,have,£300]
#I get: ['I', 'have', '\xc2\xa3300.']
```

Comment: Strings are ASCII in Python 2.

Comment: Ok, but how do i split in the way I want?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking at a limitation of the way python 2 *displays* data.

Using python 2:

```
>>> mystring = 'I have £300.'
>>> mystring.split()
['I', 'have', '\xc2\xa3300.']
```

But, observe that it will print as you want:

```
>>> print(mystring.split()[2])
£300.
```

Using python 3, by contrast, it displays as you would like:

```
>>> mystring = 'I have £300.'
>>> mystring.split()
['I', 'have', '£300.']
```

A major reason to use python 3 is its superior handling of unicode.

Comment: Any workaround - as I have python 2.6.6 on my server?

Comment: @Brana If you `print` the string itself, as opposed to a list which contains it, then it will display as you want.

Comment: In got that but there is a problem with other things such as processing the string, is it maybe possible to set default encoding to be utf-8?

Comment: _"there is a problem with other things such as processing the string"_ Can you be specific about that?

Comment: Such as replacing the specific words, or determining if 2 words are equal - as this sometimes can be a problem as every split function makes unicode chars ascii... it will probably be the best to create my own function for spliting and decode every element into utf-8 and use it always instead of default split.

Comment: Or install python 3 as I do not think that any kind of linux comes with python 3.

Comment: @Brana As an aside, figuring out if two unicode strings are "equal" is a non-trivial problem by itself.

Comment: @Brana Have you tried running `python3`?  Every linux that I use has  python3 and has had it for many years.  Python2 is still the default, `/usr/bin/python`, but version 3 is available under the name `python3`.

Comment: @roeland - are you sure? I saw that unicode is trying  to convert 2 string arguments to the same encoding (utf-8) in order to compare them, but if they can be converted it should be ok. If one is not utf-8 then it cannot compare them but thats ok by me.

Comment: @John1024 I tried /usr/bin/python3 and it doesn't work. I only use exec via php

Comment: # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
a1= u'Duda'
a2= "Duda"
print a1, a2
print a1 == a2
print "da" in a2

Comment: I use this exec command - $mcd = 'python /home/domain/public_html/test.py';
exec($mcd.' "' . addslashes($thevariable) . '" ', $out, $r);

Comment: when i just change python to python3 it doesn't work :)

Comment: @Brana **tchrist** wrote of the best posts ever about Unicode ever on SO. It was about a Perl question but most of the answer generally applies to any program using Unicode. → [              ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/4447998) (scroll down to the laundry list, and to "                 ")

Comment: @Brana and trying to process text stored in an 8-bit string (which a python 2 `str` is) will just get you trouble. First decode to `unicode`, then do your processing.

Comment: Yes, i now first use text.decode("utf-8","ignore).encode("utf-8") and most non acii chars didn't give me errors.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not with `split()`. The real problem is that the handling of unicode in python 2 is confusing.

The first line in your code produces a string, i.e. a sequence of bytes, which contains the utf-8 encoding of the symbol `£`. You can confirm this by displaying the `repr` of your original string:

```
>>> mystring
'I have \xc2\xa3300.'
```

The rest of the statements just do what you would expect them to with such input. If you want to work with unicode, create a unicode string to start with:

```
>>> mystring = u'I have £300.'
```

A far better solution, however, is to switch to Python 3. Wrapping your head around the semantics of unicode in python 2 is not worth the effort when there's such a superior alternative.