# How to make Mojolicious deal with UTF-8?

Tags: perl, unicode, utf-8

Consider the following code. This way I get "Wide character in syswrite" for a file, and garbage in a browser:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;
use Mojo::UserAgent;
use Mojo::File;

get '/' => sub {
    my $c = shift;
    my $ua  = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
    $res = $ua->get('https://...')->result;
    Mojo::File->new('resp')->spurt($res->dom->at('.some-selector')->text);
    $c->render(text => $res->body);
}

app->start;
```

But this way it works:

```
use Encode qw/encode_utf8 decode_utf8/;
Mojo::File->new('resp')->spurt(encode_utf8($res->dom->at('.some-selector')->text));
Mojo::File->new('resp')->spurt($res->body);
$c->render(text => decode_utf8($res->body));
```

Can you explain what's going on here? Why do the two of the statements not work without `Encode` module? Why does the second one work? Is there a better way to handle it? I've skimmed over [perluniintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html) and [perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html), but that's as far as I could get.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I've understood from [perluniintro](https://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html), [perlunicode](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html), and xxfelixxx's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484/why-does-modern-perl-avoid-utf-8-by-default) is that Unicode is a complex matter. You can't generally make it just work. There are bytes (octets) and text. Before handling input you most of the time have got to convert bytes to text (`decode`), and before outputting, you've got to do the reverse (`encode`). If it were not about third-party libraries, one could do `use open qw( :encoding(UTF-8) :std );`, or `binmode`. But with third-party libraries you are not always able to do so.

As such, `$res->body` is bytes, `$res->text` is text decoded from encoding specified in response. `$res->dom` takes [`$res->text`](https://github.com/kraih/mojo/blob/v7.71/lib/Mojo/Message.pm#L69) as input. So, `$res->dom->at('.some-selector')->text` is text, and `Mojo::File->new(...)->spurt()` expects to get bytes. So you have no other way, but to encode it using UTF-8. And by the way, `utf8` is not `UTF-8`. The latter is safer, so you'd better use `encode`/`decode` functions.

Then, `$c->render(text => ...);` expects text, not bytes. So you either have got to `decode('UTF-8', $res->body)`, or pass `$res->text`.

Comment: Hi. Do you know how to make log output in utf8? Here is line from console: `[1761] [info] 20650274 Contractor:ÐÐ¾ÑÑÐ¾Ð²`