# Getting unwanted line break when trying to build a string of multiple variables

Tags: xml, perl

I am new to Perl and trying to make a script that takes input from the user and then get XML data from a website based on that input together with a url and then relay it back to the user.

But I have had some issues now with make a usable link based on the input from the user.

This is my code in full:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;

my $row = 0;

use XML::LibXML;

print "\n\n\nOn what place do you need a weather report for? -> ";

my $ort = <>;

my $url1 = "http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/Västra_Götaland/";
my $url2 = "/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml";

my $url = join('', $url1,$ort,$url2);

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $url);

print "\n\nSee below the weather for ", $ort, ":\n\n";

foreach my $weatherdata ($dom->findnodes('//time')) {

    if($row != 10){ 

        my $temp = $weatherdata->findvalue('./temperature/@value');
        my $value = $weatherdata->findvalue('./@from');

        my $valuesub = substr $value, 11, 5;

        print "At ", $valuesub, " the temperature will be: ", $temp, "C\n";

        $row++;
    }
}

print "\n\n";
```

The crusial bit I assume is this one:

```
my $ort = <>;

my $url1 = "http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/Västra_Götaland/";
my $url2 = "/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml";

my $url = join('', $url1,$ort,$url2);

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(location => $url);
```

When I run it I get this:
[image]

It enters a line break and then the link is broken.

I think the issue lies with `$ort` cause when I try to print only `$ort` out with something comming after I get a line break aswell.

I hope I explained it clearly or you can perhaps tell me what needs improvement.

Comment: Also missing is `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`, plus some encoding when building the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I would gladly take tips on how to sort out my encoding problem with the url if you have the time. The use you mentioned created a whole new type of errors to my code.

When adding as input: Åmål

I got this for response:
utf8 "\x8F" does not map to Unicode at test4.pl line 11.
utf8 "\x86" does not map to Unicode at test4.pl line 11.

Comment: Not enough info.

Comment: Also gets Could not create file parser context for file "http://www.yr.no/place/Sweden/V├â┬ñstra_G├â┬Âtaland/\x8Fm\x86l/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml": No error at test4.pl line 18

Comment: Using same code as above with your addition you posted 2 hours ago.

Comment: My addition? I didn't provide code for it. Not the place to be asking new questions!

Comment: What? You suggested adding  `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`  to my code. you also said I was missing some encoding when building a URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That newline comes from your terminal. You can use the [`chomp`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) function to remove it:

```
my $ort = <>;
chomp($ort);
```

It is usual to see this alternatively written in one line, which gives the same result:

```
chomp( my $ort = <> );
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm! Now I only have some encoding issues to dig into :P

Comment: I’m happy it sorted out that part! About the encoding, check the following question. The answer by tchrist is a great collection and reference for the settings we often use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6162484