# Reading file breaks encoding in Perl

Tags: perl, encoding, escaping

I have script for reading html files in Perl, it works, but it breaks encoding.

**This is my script:**

```
use utf8;
use Data::Dumper;

open my $fr, '<', 'file.html' or die "Can't open file $!";
my $content_from_file = do { local $/; <$fr> };

print Dumper($content_from_file);
```

**Content of file.html:**

```
<span class="previews-counter">Počet hodnotení: [%product.rating_votes%]</span>
<a href="#" title="[%L10n.msg('Zobraziť recenzie')%]" class="previews-btn js-previews-btn">[%L10n.msg('Zobraziť recenzie')%]</a>
```

**Output from reading:**

```
<span class=\"previews-counter\">Po\x{10d}et hodnoten\x{ed}: [%product.rating_votes%]</span>
<a href=\"#\" title=\"[%L10n.msg('Zobrazi\x{165} recenzie')%]\" class=\"previews-btn js-previews-btn\">[%L10n.msg('Zobrazi\x{165} recenzie')%]</a>
```

As you can see lot of characters are escaped, how can I read this file and show content of it as it is?

Comment: Did you `use Data::Dumper` somewhere?

Comment: @ernix yes, why?

Comment: I've just tried to run your script.  Try `open my $fr, '<:raw', 'file.html' or die "Can't open file $!";`,  it seems your script modifies IO layer, to read all strings from open as UTF8 decoded. see https://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html and https://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html

Comment: Start by reading http://perldoc.perl.org/perluniintro.html

Comment: I also usually suggest using [File::Slurper](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Slurper) for reading a file into a string.

Comment: Data::Dumper is escaping high-bit characters and metacharacters in your string, this is a feature of Data::Dumper which is designed for debugging. Don't use Data::Dumper if you want to output the actual string.

Comment: I recommend reading https://perlgeek.de/en/article/encodings-and-unicode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You open the file with perl's default encoding:

```
open my $fh, '<', ...;
```

If that encoding doesn't match the actual encoding, Perl might translate some characters incorrectly. If you know the encoding, specify it in the `open` mode:

```
open my $fh, '<:utf8', ...;
```

You aren't done yet, though. Now that you have a probably decoded string, you want to output it. You have the same problem again. The standard output file handle's encoding has to match what you are trying to print to. If you've set up your terminal (or whatever) to expect UTF-8, you need to actually output UTF-8. One way to fix that is to make the standard filehandles use `UTF-8`:

```
use open qw(:std :utf8);
```

You have `use utf8`, but that only signals the encoding for your program file.

I've written a much longer primer for Perl and Unicode in the back of [Learning Perl](https://www.learning-perl.com). The StackOverflow question [Why does modern Perl avoid UTF-8 by default?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6162484/2766176) has lots of good advice.

Comment: To be more specific: the standard output file handle's encoding has to match what you are trying to print **to**. Normally, this is a terminal that expects UTF-8. Don't use the `:utf8` layer, use `:encoding(UTF-8)`.

Comment: I changed open statement to `open my $fr, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $file or die "Can't open file $!";` and I included at the beginning `use open qw(:std :utf8);`, but it is still broken and added `binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';` before `Dumper`.

Comment: It's not broken. It's a feature of Data::Dumper. @Grinnz already told you to not use Data::Dumper. Why don't you just print the string? Is there any reason why you are using Data::Dumper other than debugging?

Comment: @tinita oh, it's is ok, it just Dumper breaks, so then it is solved :)