# Perl multi-byte character encoding for HTML

Tags: perl, character-encoding, multibyte

I'm being passed a string such as:

```
my $x = "Zakłady Kuźnicze";
```

If you examine it closer you see that those two weird letters are actually composed of two bytes:

```
foreach (split(//, $x)) { print $_.' '.ord($_)."\n"; }

Z 90
a 97
k 107
� 197
� 130
a 97
d 100
y 121
  32
K 75
u 117
� 197
� 186
n 110
i 105
c 99
z 122
e 101
```

I want to convert this to encoded HTML using the codes described here: https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_latin_extended_a.asp

So I need a function such that:

```
print encode_it($x)."\n";
```

yields:

```
Zak&#322;ady Ku&#382;nice
```

I've tried `HTML::Entities::encode` and `HTML::Entities::encode_numeric`, but these yield:

```
Zak&Aring;&#130;ady Ku&Aring;&ordm;nicze

Zak&#xC5;&#x82;ady Ku&#xC5;&#xBA;nicze
```

Which does not help, it renders as:

```
ZakÅ‚ady KuÅºnicze
```

Can anyone advise how to achieve this?

EDIT:

Like ikegami showed it works if `use utf8` is used AND the string is set in the program:

```
perl -e 'use utf8; chomp; printf "%X\n", ord for split //, "Zakłady Kuźnicze"'
5A
61
6B
142
61
64
79
20
4B
75
17A
6E
69
63
7A
65
```

...but my input is actually coming in via STDIN, and it's not working from STDIN:

```
echo "Zakłady Kuźnicze" | perl -ne 'use utf8; chomp; printf "%X\n", ord for split //'
5A
61
6B
C5
82
61
64
79
20
4B
75
C5
BA
6E
69
63
7A
65
```

What subtlety am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perl expects the source to be either ASCII<sup>[1]</sup> (`no utf8;`, the default) or UTF-8 (`use utf8;`). You appear to have a file encoded using UTF-8, but you didn't tell Perl that, so it sees

```
my $x = "Zak\xC5\x82ady Ku\xC5\xBAnicze";
```

rather than the intended

```
my $x = "Zak\x{142}ady Ku\x{17A}nicze";
```

Example (UTF-8 terminal):

```
$ diff -U 0 \
   <( perl -e'no utf8;  printf "%X\n", ord for split //, "Zakłady Kuźnicze"' ) \
   <( perl -e'use utf8; printf "%X\n", ord for split //, "Zakłady Kuźnicze"' )
--- /dev/fd/63  2020-01-17 20:04:23.407591294 -0800
+++ /dev/fd/62  2020-01-17 20:04:23.407591294 -0800
@@ -4,2 +4 @@
-C5
-82
+142
@@ -12,2 +11 @@
-C5
-BA
+17A
```

Add `use utf8;`.

---

1. An 8-bit clean version of ASCII, meaning that any byte with the 8th bit set in a string or regex literal results in a character with the same value.

Comment: Thank you! For expedience in the question I set the string in the program but it's actually coming from STDIN and not working then (see edit)

Comment: Same problem: You still didn't decode your inputs. `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';` will handle STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR and even set the default for uses of `open` in the lexical scope.

Answer (score 2):

As @ikegami said, `use utf8;` will decode your source code from UTF-8 so that string literals and other symbols can be interpreted as intended. Like the source code, input to your code is also in bytes, and usually UTF-8 encoded if it's text. So depending where it is coming from you have several options to decode it into useful characters. Below lists different options, you only need one for a particular stream of input.

From STDIN:

```
use open ':std', IN => ':encoding(UTF-8)'; # also affects read filehandles opened in this scope
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)'; # also affects STDOUT, STDERR, and all filehandles opened in this scope
binmode *STDIN, ':encoding(UTF-8)'; # STDIN only
```

Or these switches for oneliners:

```
-CI # STDIN only
-CS # STDIN, STDOUT, STDERR
-Mopen=':std,IN,:encoding(UTF-8)' # equivalent to first "use open" above
```

From handles you open yourself:

```
use open IN => ':encoding(UTF-8)'; # all read handles opened in this scope
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)'; # also affects write handles
open my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', 'example.txt' or die "Failed to open example.txt: $!";
binmode $fh, ':encoding(UTF-8)'; # to set on already opened handle
```

Or these switches for oneliners:

```
-Ci # read handles only
-CD # all handles opened
-Mopen='IN,:encoding(UTF-8)' # equivalent to first "use open" above
```

The above `use open` and `-C` options also apply to ARGV (the handle used by `-n`, `-p`, or the `<>`/`readline` operator to read filenames passed as arguments - this is different from when it is used to read STDIN). `-C` switches can be combined, for example `-CSD` will set it for STDIN/OUT/ERR as well as all handles opened.

Finally, you can decode the data itself after reading rather than affecting any handles globally (below assuming the data is in `$_`):

```
utf8::decode($_) or die "Invalid UTF-8"; # in place, does not require "use utf8"
$_ = Encode::decode('UTF-8', $_); # with Encode loaded
$_ = Encode::Simple::decode_utf8($_); # with Encode::Simple loaded
```

Just remember if you want to output such decoded characters, or characters from literals with `use utf8;` set for your source code, the STDOUT, STDERR, and other write handles need the same treatment, or you need to encode the data to UTF-8 before printing.

Some useful links:

- [open pragma](https://perldoc.pl/open)
- [-C switch](https://perldoc.pl/perlrun#-C-%5Bnumber/list%5D)
- [utf8 pragma+functions](https://perldoc.pl/utf8)
- [Encode](https://perldoc.pl/Encode)
- [Encode::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Simple)
- [perlunitut](https://perldoc.pl/perlunitut)
- [more than you ever need to know about handling UTF-8 in Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/5848200)