# How to remove leading whitespace denoted with ? using rename in MacOS

Tags: perl, rename

I have directories that looks like this in my MacOs:

[image]

For example `???9-24_v_hMrgprx2` where `???` is actually
white spaces. What I want to do is to use [`rename`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html) to remove those leading white spaces.

I tried this but failed.

```
rename  "s/\s*//g"  *
```

What's the right way to do it?

---

**Update**

Hexdump looks like this:

```
    ls  | hexdump -C
00000000  e3 80 80 39 2d 32 34 5f  76 5f 68 4d 72 67 70 72  |...9-24_v_hMrgpr|
00000010  78 32 0a                                          |x2.|
00000013
```

Answer (score 3):

Verify what those characters are first, since macOS doesn't display ASCII whitespace characters in filenames as ? (unless you have some weird encoding issue going on). It would help if you added information like this to your question:

```
$ touch "   touched"
$ ls -l *touched
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 brian  staff  0 Aug 18 13:52    touched
$ ls *touched | hexdump -C
00000000  20 20 20 74 6f 75 63 68  65 64 0a                 |   touched.|
0000000b
```

For rename, you've almost got it right if those leading characters were whitespace. However, you want to anchor the pattern so you only match whitespace at the beginning of the name:

```
rename 's/\A\s+//' *
```

---

Now that we know your filenames start with U+3000 (which is whitespace), I can see what's going on.

There are various versions of `rename`. Larry Wall wrote one, @tchrist wrote one based on that (and I use that), and [File::Rename](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Rename) is another modification of Larry's original. Then there is [Aristotle's version](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=303814).

The problem with my `rename` (from @tchrist) is that it doesn't interpret the filenames as UTF-8. So, U+3000, looks like the three bytes you see: `e3 80 80`. I'm guessing that your font might not support any of those. There could be all sorts of things going on. See [@tchrist's Unicode answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/2766176).

I can create the file:

```
% perl -CS -le 'print qq(\x{3000}abc)' | xargs touch
```

I can easily see the file, but I have a font that can display that character:

```
$ ls -l *abc
-rw-rw-r--  1 brian  staff  0 Aug 22 02:44 　abc
```

But, when I try to rename it, using the `-n` for a dry run, I get no output (so, no matching files to change):

```
$ rename -n 's/\A\s+//' *abc
```

If I run `perl` directly and give it `-CSA` to treat the standard file handles (`-CS`) and the command-line arguments (`-CA`) as UTF-8, the file matches and the replacement happens:

```
$ perl -CSA `which rename` -n 's/\A\s+//' *abc
rename 　abc abc
```

So, for my particular version, I can edit the shebang line to have the options I need. This works for me because I know my terminal settings, so it might not work everywhere for all settings:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl -CSA
```

But the trick is how did I get that version of `rename`? I'm pretty sure I installed some module from CPAN that gave it to me, but what? I'd supply a patch if I could.

Comment: Hi, I tried, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Tried what? Can you show the hex dump of the names?

Comment: I updated the OP with hexdump.

Comment: `ls` does display unknown or unprintable characters as `?`

Comment: Well, something displays those as `?`, but it's likely more a problem with locale and fonts. The now-known filename displays just fine for me with no `?`.

Answer (score 2):

E3 80 80 is the UTF-8 encoding of [U+3000](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/3000/index.htm) which is a CJK whitespace character.

`rename` is not a standard utility on MacOS, and there are several popular utilities with this name, so what exactly works will depend on which version you have installed. The syntax looks like you have [this one](https://manpages.org/rename), from the Perl distribution. Maybe try

```
rename 's/\xe3\x80\x80//' *
```

Comment: Heh, you link to Larry Wall's version of `rename`, and I see that I have @tchrist's version based on that. And, that's different from the version from `File::Rename`, which is also based on Larry's.