Incorrect output of UTF-8 encoded string in UTF-8 environment
While finding a solution for How to solve Perl's `length 'für' == 4` for `LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"`? I wrote another little test program:
It seems Perl (5.18.2) does not output UTF-8 encoded strings correctly in an UTF-8 Linux (SLES12 SP5) environment when the strings are interpreted as UTF-8.
The basic problem was that (e.g.) string "Gemäß" being read from a file had a length of 7 instead of 5, so I wrote this test program ("length.pl", the first test is "commented out" in an odd way):
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

=begin debug

use utf8;

print length('Gemäß'), "\n";

=end debug

=cut

if (open(my $fh, "<:encoding(UTF-8)", 'length.txt')) {
    while (<$fh>) {
        chomp;
        print length($_), ':', $_, "\n";
    }
    close($fh);
} else {
    warn "length.txt: $!\n";
}

The input file "length.txt" just contains a single line, like this
> cat length.txt
Gemäß
> hexdump -C length.txt
00000000  47 65 6d c3 a4 c3 9f 0a                           |Gem.....|
00000008
> ./length.pl
5:Gem▒▒
>  locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
> vi length.pl # remove the ":encoding(UTF-8)" from open
> ./length.pl
7:Gemäß

So the length is correct, but the output on the screen is wrong.
When dropping :encoding(UTF-8) from the open call, then the string length is wrong, but the output is correct.
I'm using an SSH session via PuTTY with setting "Remote character set:" set to "UTF-8" (just in case someone would ask for that).
Obviously I'd like to have both (for correct UTF-8 input), the string length and correct text output.
One Problem fixed, another one created
(I should ask a new question as it is actually a different problem, but to avoid a cascade of related question, I add it to this one)
Unfortunately the test case was incomplete for the whole scenario:
The real program reads UTF-8 input from a file, processes the contents, then writes the contents to a different file.
While https://stackoverflow.com/a/78851883/6607497 helped to fix the length issue, and a print inside the debugger shows the correct content encoding (I think), the content in the file written is wrong.
For example:
Say $templatecontains Mit freundlichen Grüßen, and $mf is a temporary file ($mf = File::Temp->new('TEMPLATE' => 'msg-XXXXXX', 'UNLINK' => 0)), then after print $mf $template; the file contains Mit freundlichen Gr▒▒en, ("üß" encoded as 0xfc 0xdf).
Before the "fix", the file content was correct.
I had tried any combinations of
use utf8;
use open ':locale';
use open IO => ':locale';
use open IO => 'utf8';
use open ':std' => ':locale';
use open ':std' => 'utf8';
use feature qw(unicode_strings);


Call binmode on the temp filehandle : https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Temp#BINMODE

@clamp Can you explain a bit more (maybe in an answer)? Does Perl assume (under "use utf8" and "use IO => 'utf8') that all strings read from files are UTF-8? If so wouldn't Perl keep the strings "as is" when writing "as UTF-8" (as per "use IO => 'utf8')?

You should really ask separate questions and take the time to write an mre. In the update to your original question, you are printing to a File::Temp handle. Since the effect of the open pragma is lexical, this does not affect the filehandle created by File::Temp. The synopsis of File::Handle shows you how to add the utf8 layer: binmode( $fh, ":utf8" );

Maybe I mis-interpreted "lexical": I thought when "using" at the global level, it would affect all sub-levels, but if I'd use it in some nested block it wouldn't affect outer blocks.

The topmost lexical scope is the file.

Also File::Temp is documented to open files in binary mode (it uses sysopen internally).

(On binary mode being used): "The principle of biggest surprise" was applied again; I did not read that part.

You didn't tell perl to output utf-8. At every boundary, you need to ensure the right things are happening.
This pragma will do it:
use open qw(:std :utf8);

Or with -C from the command line:
% perl -CS ...

There's a Unicode primer at the end of Learning Perl.

The answer could need some more explanation: Why is the string output correctly if no encoding is specified; does Perl just copy input to output? And what happens if Perl has a valid UTF-8 string; will Perl try to "fix" the correct string on output?

On your book recommendation: You are recommending a book where you are co-author (nothing against that) and that is not available yet. I'd prefer information that I can read here.

For the test case presented use open qw(:std :utf8); will do, but for the real program use open IO =>':locale'; seems to be the solution (after having read "open (3pm)").

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/6163129/10667839

Users may also like to know that the Perl debugger does not use the encoding set (at least for 5.18..2). For example (in the real program) x $result gave me 0  '"ALPHA/GLC: A"..."chtigung f▒r|"', while print $result displayed "ALPHA/GLC: A"..."chtigung für|" (Before you are wondering: $result is a debug output by itself, thus the odd content).

The book has been available for years, and I put in the answer the relevant parts.  I don't know what more explanation you need.

The debuggers output handle is special. you need to add binmode DB::OUT,":utf8" to your code.

@briandfoy The link targets to "Pre-order Learning Perl 8th Edition", so I guessed the book is not available yet.

An upcoming 8th edition does imply the existence of a current 7th edition...

The 8th edition has been available for years, but even then the previous editions have the Unicode Primer. At some point, you really need to look beyond the surface of things and reasonably try to help yourself.

On the book and the link: The confusing part was that you referred to the "Unicode primer" using a link, but following that link one cannot see any "Unicode primer". So IMHO the link is not useful, actually. Instead you might refer to the printed book. - Talking about the answer: You could explain what use open qw(:std :utf8); does exactly, or at least to an extent necessary to answer the question.

The link is to a website for a book. Buy the book to read it. For open, read the open docs. You have quite a bit of low-effort energy here. There's plenty out there that allows you to answer your own questions instead of relying on me to personally explain everything to you.
